# Make Windows .exe file by compiling code on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm using Linux mint, and I'm writing a simple C++ console program that takes input and does some basic string manipulations, and output the result to .txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define MAXSIZE 12

using namespace std;
int main() {
    string name;
    string number;
    cout << "Enter name:\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter number:\n";
    cin >> number;
    string new_number = "+972";
    for (int i = 1; i < number.size(); ++i) {
        if(number[i]=='-')
            continue;
        else
            new_number += number[i];

    }
    string link = "http://wa.me/";
    link+=new_number;
    string text_with_name = "שלום ";
    text_with_name += name;
    text_with_name += "\nמודים לך על זה שאתה שמוק. נשמח לא לתת לך שירות, תודה..\n";
    fstream file("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
    file << text_with_name << endl << link << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wish to save this file as .exe and run it on windows. when trying to do `g++ -o pr.exe myfile.cpp`. It failed to run on a windows os.

what am I missing along the way?

thanks!

Comment: Compile on windows using a native compiler or use a cross compiler.

Comment: Please post the source code, not screenshot!

Comment: It's generating a native Linux PE with your specified extension. So it's not a native Windows PE.

Comment: thanks. any more information regarding to how I could obtain my desired result? :-)

Comment: In short, you need a special flavor of GCC, called MinGW. It should be in a package called `g++-mingw-w64-x86-64`.

Comment: Hi, I already have g++-mingw-w64 installed.

Comment: Then you just need to use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` instead of `g++`.

Comment: Also please use `@username` when replying, otherwise I don't get notifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245938/discussion-between-dani-l-n-and-holyblackcat).